# Asp.net losing number formatting on refresh

Tags: razor, asp.net-core

I have a simple asp.net core 2.0 mvc application. 
In the data model I have a decimal number which I have formatted to 2 decimal numbers using data annotations:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "N2")]
public decimal MyValue { get; set; }
```

Model is passed to the view by the controller and is displayed in the view using this code:

```
 @model MyModel
 <p>@Model.MyValue</p>
```

This works fine and the value is displayed with 2 decimals when I initially browse to the page. But when I hit refresh in the browser, only a single decimal is displayed.

I am getting the same behavior when testing on my PC and when running on Azure with either Chrome or Edge browsers.

Interestingly, if I view page source, there are two decimals in the HTML.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If there are 2 decimals in the source, there will be 2 on the display too (unless CSS has done something to it). We're going to need to see this in action I think, on the surface this sounds impossible.

Comment: While building a mini solution to replicate and share, I realized that the formatting is not working at all. Something else is doing that initial format. In the blank project the number is not formatted in the view. I have to use formatting in the view to get 2 decimals:     @($"{Model.MyValue:N2}"). So dataannotation formatting is not working in view. Perhaps I need to start a new question?

Comment: Well the formatting won't work if you use the code above. You need to use `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.MyValue)`

Comment: I thought this is no longer necessary in asp.net core.

Comment: You may be getting confused with view components? The code above will literally just do a `ToString()` on the value and throw it out to the client - the `DisplayFormat` attribute will be ignored.